# Fixing the element number in each row

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4, vuejs2

```
<template>
  <div @keyup="moveIndex" tabindex="0">
    <h2>Kanal Listesi</h2>
    <div class="container">
      <div v-for="(channel,index) in channels" :key="index">
        <div v-if="channel.ChName">
          <img
            :src="'http://uyanik.tv/conf/images/'+channel.Image"
            height="100px"
            :class="{selectedIndex:currentIndex === index}"
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import channelz from "../trsubs.channels.json";
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      channels: channelz.Root.Channels.Channel,
      currentIndex: 1,
      channelPerRow: 9
    };
  },

}
</script>

<style scoped>
.selectedIndex {
  border: 5px solid;
  border-color: aquamarine;
  opacity: 0.6;
  transition: 0.2s;
}
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  align-items: flex-start;
}
div > div > div > div > img{
  margin: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
}
</style>
```

I am currently trying to fix the number of elements in each row in my template because the app will mostly be used in variety of devices with lower resolutions. Isn't there any way to fix the element number per row regardless of device resolution? Thanks!

Comment: Can you post what you are doing in `moveIndex` method?

Comment: Sure. I am adding the moveIndex function too. It just changes the index.

Comment: Thanks for updating. If you want to fix number of channels in a row. Why don't you add `min-width` to your row container and add `overflow-x:auto` on it.

Comment: And you would also have to update your loop to render elements in chunks of max elements.

Comment: Thanks. It works smoothly for now. I will keep you updated once my problem resolves 100%. Nice regards!